# integral as limit of a sum

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Consider $f(N)=1-\frac1N \sum_{k=1}^N (\frac{k-1}{N})^n\quad,n,N\in \mathbb N $. Why does $\lim_{N\to\infty}f(N)=1-\int_0^1 x^ndx$

In the text I was reading  this is just stated without any explanation. Why is this true?

Comment: @ J.D the  sum $\frac1N\sum (\frac{k-1}{N})^n$ is exactly the Riemann sum for the function $x^n$

Comment: ahh yes, thanks Minz :)